# Eigen Tensor Code terribly slow

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm new to Eigen Tensors so probably I'm doing something terribly wrong. I have a code that calculates Z-Scores of a difference between two matrices of floats. I've discovered that the code is running 500x times slower than the same code in Python and numpy.
What am I doing wrong?

Code in C++

```
  int scale = atoi(argv[1]);
  Eigen::array<int, 2> bbcast({scale, 1});
  long startTime = get_nanos();
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> a(2, 5);
  a.setRandom();
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> b(2, 5);
  b.setRandom();
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> scaled_a = a.broadcast(bbcast);  
  Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> scaled_b = b.broadcast(bbcast);  

  Eigen::array<int, 1> dims({0 /* dimension to reduce */});
  Eigen::array<int, 2> good_dims{{1,(int)scaled_a.dimension(1)}};
  auto means = (scaled_a - scaled_b).mean(dims).reshape(good_dims);
  std::cout << means << std::endl;
  printf("Calculated means, took %f seconds\n",(float)(get_nanos() - startTime) / 1000000000L);

  Eigen::array<int, 2> bcast({(int)scaled_a.dimension(0), 1});
  auto submean = (scaled_a - scaled_b) - means.broadcast(bcast);
  auto stds = submean.mean(dims).reshape(good_dims).abs().square().mean(dims).reshape(good_dims).sqrt();
  std::cout << stds << std::endl;
  printf("Calculated std, took %f seconds\n",(float)(get_nanos() - startTime) / 1000000000L);
```

This runs about 3 seconds on my  Linux VM with 20000 by 5 matrices of float

Code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import time
start = time.time()
a = np.random.rand(2*10000,5)
b = np.random.rand(2*10000,5)
stds = np.std(a - b, axis = 0)
means = np.mean(a - b, axis = 0)
#diffs = np.sum(np.abs(net_out - correct_out)/stds,axis=1)
diffs = np.abs(a - b - means)/stds
print(diffs)
print("Took", time.time() - start )
```

This runs 0.0068 seconds on the same VM.

Thanks a lot,
Moshe

Comment: Let's see how you compiled your code, please.

Comment: Straightforward g++ ./eigen_test.cc -o ./eigen_test -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/

Comment: don't forget compiler optimizations: `-O3` and `-march=native` might also help to fully use your CPU.

Comment: `-NDEBUG`, turning off debug mode assertions will also give a nice boost.

Comment: @DavidAce Shouldn't it be `-DNDEBUG`?

Comment: @Ela782 yes! my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2D tensors, better use `Matrix` or `Array`, this will lead to simpler code:

```
ArrayXXd a = ArrayXXd::Random(2*10000,5);
ArrayXXd b = ArrayXXd::Random(2*10000,5);
auto means = (a-b).colwise().mean().eval();
auto stds = (((a-b).rowwise()-means).square().colwise().sum() / (a.rows()-1)).sqrt().eval();
ArrayXXd diffs = abs((a-b).rowwise() - means).rowwise()/stds;
```

Note the `.eval()` for the lines using `auto`, see [why](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

This code takes `0.000324919s` when compiled with gcc and `-O3` on an average laptop (without considering the random number generation which is likely much more expensive but not representative).

Here is the Tensor version I came up, again notice the `eval()`calls:

```
int n = a.dimension(0);
Eigen::array<int, 1> dims({0 /* dimension to reduce */});
Eigen::array<int, 2> good_dims{{1,(int)a.dimension(1)}};
Eigen::array<int,2> bc({n,1});

auto means = (a - b).mean(dims).eval();
auto submean = (a - b) - means.reshape(good_dims).broadcast(bc);
auto stds = (submean.square().eval().sum(dims) * 1.f/(float(n-1))).sqrt().eval();
diffs = submean.abs() / stds.reshape(good_dims).broadcast(bc);
```

but it seems to be quite slower, about 0.007s here. To view a `Tensor` as an `Array`, you can use `Map`:

```
Map<const ArrayXXf> a(tensor_a.data(), tensor_a.dimension(0), tensor_a.dimension(1));
```

Comment: Can I convert from Tensors (which I get from Tensorflow) to matrices?